# How do I calculate Coriolis force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

For figuring Coriolis force, I've seen this equation:

$$
\vec a_{cor} = -2\vec \omega \times \vec v
$$

So, say that I have an angular velocity of 5 rpms, and a velocity of 10 m/s going toward the axis of rotation. How do I go about solving this equation? I studied vector math for about a week in high school, and never quite understood it. Please explain like I am 5, or an English major (*full disclosure: BA in English Literature*).

**Note: I don't want you to *solve* it for me, just explain *how* to solve it, or link me somewhere that does. Thanks!**

Comment: Hi. Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting at the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. From the top answer on the Meta post: "We expect you to narrow down the problem to the particular concept that's giving you trouble and ask about that specifically." I want to understand Coriolis force in specific situations (e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352349/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/360168/), but I barely understand vector math. I was hoping that would count in my favor. So far the answers are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for bothering to check the links. :) And glad it worked out for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\vec{\omega}$ is a vector: its direction is given by the right hand rule: curl the fingers of your right hand in the direction of the rotation and see where your thumb points. The magnitude of this vector is the rotation rate in radians per second (IOW, you'll need to convert the 5 rpm datum to radians per second - remember there are $2\pi$ radians in a full rotation ($360^\circ$) and of course 60 seconds in a minute.)

Now you should realize that $\vec{\omega}$ points along the axis of rotation, so since $\vec{v}$ points towards the axis of rotation, the two vectors are *perpendicular*.

The rest follows from the definition of the cross product: the magnitude of the cross product is the product of the magnitudes of the individual vectors times the sine of the angle between them (but since they are perpendicular, that's $\sin{90^\circ} = 1$). The direction of the cross product is again given by the right hand rule: put the two vectors on a common tail, point the straightened fingers of your right hand in the direction of the first vector, but make sure that when you curl your fingers, they point in the direction of the second vector; the direction of the cross product is perpendicular to the two vectors in the direction of your thumb.

And don't forget that you have to multiply the resulting cross product by $-2$, that is double its magnitude and *reverse* its direction (because of the minus sign).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea what units $\vec \omega$ needed to be in. I'd heard about the right-hand rule, but didn't realize it was applicable here. With your help, I was able to derive an answer that looks right!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define the parameters of your problem. Let's use cylindrical coordinates, using the base $(\mathbf{e}_z, \mathbf{e}_r, \mathbf{e}_\theta)$, where $\mathbf{e}_z$ is the axis of rotation.There is an inertial frame of reference $\mathcal{R}_0$, and another one $\mathcal{R}$ which rotates with and angular velocity $\mathbf{\omega} = \omega \mathbf{e}_z$ around $\mathcal{R}_0$, where $\omega = 5\,\textrm{rpm}$. Now, we are studying an object moving with a velocity $\mathbf{v} = -v\mathbf{e}_r$ where $v =10\,\textrm{m/s}$.

Now, you have to use the formula giving the Coriolis acceleration: $\mathbf{a}_c = -2\mathbf{\omega}\times\mathbf{v}$. To find the acceleration, you must find the cross product of two vectors. First of all, you can use the bilinearity of the cross product, ie. the fact that it behaves like a normal multiplication, except that it is not symmetric:

$$(\omega \mathbf{e}_z) \times (-v\mathbf{e}_r) = -\omega v (\mathbf{e}_z \times\mathbf{e}_r)$$

Finally, the cross product of two base vectors can be found easily: use the right-hand rule. Here, $\mathbf{e}_z$ is represented by your middle finger, $\mathbf{e}_z$ by your thumb, so their cross product (in this order) gives your forefinger, that is $\mathbf{e}_\theta$.